# Word choice for "Educationally Enriched"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, synonyms

Is there any word which replace the phrase "Educationally enriched"? I was trying  to write an essay where I defined a state where every people are educated. To define that I was taking help of phrase "Educationally enriched". Now I want to replace it with some better English.

Comment: What do you think *educationally enriched* means (aside from each individual word)? How is is it different than simply *educated* (a word that you use in your own question)?

Comment: With "educated" do you mean simply that people "receive an education" or that they are e.g. accomplished, cultured, erudite, etc? I posted an answer but that assumed the first one to some degree. Also do you mean a state as in a "situation" or a "nation-state"?

Comment: Can you give an example of a sentence/short passage you've written where you have currently used "educationally enriched", for context?

Answer (score 0):

## "universal education"

(e.g. [World of 7 Billion](https://www.worldof7billion.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/The-Importance-of-Universal-Education.pdf))

> **Benefits of universal education**
>
> In the world’s more developed countries, school attendance is compulsory and public schools provide a free education for children and adolescents
>
> [...]
>
> Education is a human right and a strong catalyst for social progress. According to UNICEF, getting every
>   child in school and learning is essential to reducing global poverty, improving health, fostering peace,
>   bolstering democracy, improving environmental sustainability and increasing gender equality.

Universal education refers to attendance at school (in the 'younger years' at least) for everyone, rather than just a privileged elite.

## "universal access to education"

(e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_access_to_education))

> the ability of all people to have equal opportunity in education, regardless of their social class, gender, ethnicity background or physical and mental disabilities.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_access_to_education) The term is used both in college admission for the middle and lower classes, and in assistive technology[3] for the disabled.

This relates to [a policy of / situation of] having education available in theory to all, despite potential hindrances such as disabilities, disadvantaged social class, etc.

It's different from "universal education" in that it isn't compulsory or even widespread, but is about people being able to take up the opportunity if they want to. (I don't think this meets your criteria of 'a state where everyone is educated' though..)